# How to get all the properties/funcs of Swift object?

Tags: swift, reflection

These are my classes:

```
    class Shape: NSObject {
    var prop1:String?
    let prop2:String = "Shape Default"
    func printEverything(){
        var reflection = reflect(self)
        for var i = 0 ; i < reflection.count ; i++ {
            var (prop,mirror) = reflection[i]
            println(prop);
        }
    }
}

class Rect: Shape {
    var prop3:String?
    let prop4:String = "Rect Default"
    func func2(){
        // body2
    }
}

var aRect = Rect()
aRect.printEverything()
```

However printEverything only showed: super, prop3, prop4.
I was expecting to get the whole inheritance, namely: `super`, `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3`, `prop4`, `printEverything`, `func2`.

Also, how can I set these property from the reflection?

Thanks

Comment: Swift doesn't really support reflection yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the properties. If you also want the properties of the base class, then you could try using [EVRevlection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection). See its reflectedSub method for how you could get the properties of the base class. It's in the item with the key super